# Page View Controller With A Map Page: How Should I Move Away From The Map Page?

Tags: ios10, swift4

I have a page view controller wherein one of the pages is a map view. When I land on the map view I'm stuck: swipes cause the map to pan (which, of course, I want) and so I can no longer switch to another page by swiping. Can someone suggest a good way to deal with this?

I am uncertain as to what the best user experience should be. I realize that I am perhaps asking for an opinion but I really feel stuck and there might be a generally accepted way to deal with this scenario.

Comment: It seems that you could either inset the map within the view controller’s root view (allowing swipes from the edges to be clearly recognized as page swipes) or add buttons to manually navigate between the various pages. The question is not so much as how to do this technically than how to design a UX where the user’s intent is unambiguous.

Comment: @Rob. I already have the buttons but wanted to also support swiping. The inset that you suggest sounds like the right way to go. I think that a user would quickly understand how to work with that. Thanks a bunch!